# How to add different style to numbers on html?

Tags: php, html, css, symfony

Is it possible to style the numbers in a page?
I want to change the font size and family of my numbers in whole page, for example user has inserted some text which includes text and numbers. i want to add some style just to the numbers. (the body has X for font-family and i want my numbers to have Y as their font-family)

- I use php and ORM in server side (Symfony Framework).

is there any solution? specially with css.

Comment: Please include your code in your question. Let us know what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Numbers are in other way simply a kind of text.

So you can add style to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that can help you. everytime you want to put a number inside your html page you wrap it with `<span class="numbers"></span>` and you add your style in css files like this

```
.numbers
{
    color : red;
    /* your code */
}
```

if you're using php and retreiving data from database, you have to wrap all numbers before you display them. The solution is to create a function that you should apply on every column you got from your database. The function is :

```
function wrap_numbers($str)
{
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value)
        $str = preg_replace('/ '  . $value . '/',  "<span class='numbers'>" . $value . "</span>", $str, 1);
    return $str;
}
```

Now let's say you have a column in your database that has this value :

```
$str = "This is a number 123 this is another one 456";
```

before you print `$str`, you have to apply the function like this

```
$str = wrap_numbers($str);
```

if you print your $str, you'll get your numbers with different style, and if you want to know what is EXACTLY inside $str you do this

```
var_dump($str);
```

and the result is :

```
string 'This is a number<span class='numbers'>123</span> this is another one<span class='numbers'>456</span>'
```

Comment: it will be useful when i inserted the number, but whats the solution for numbers which comes from database? for example a text which has some numbers in it.

Comment: all you have to do is to create a function that looks for all numbers inside your string (coming from database) and wrap them inside `<span class='number'></span>` before you print your string

Comment: what is the server-side langage you're using? php?

Comment: @parisssss I updated my answer, and I added the function that helps you wrap your numbers with <span>

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your numbers in `span` tags with a class which will have a special CSS setting. For example

html:

```
some text <span class='prettyNumber'>123</span> other text
```

css:

```
.prettyNumber{
    font-size: 2em; /** or anything you want **/
}
```

Numbers are just a type of text, you style them the same way as you would style any other strings - by wrapping them in an element and adding style to it. If you want to add style to them post process, for example by parsing them from the page, then just don't it's certainly not a good approach.

**Update for wrapping of the result:**

After you retrieve the string from the database and store it in let's say `$result`, then you can do the following to wrap the numbers inside of it:

```
$result = 'some 123 example string';
$numberRegex = '/(\d+)/i';
$replacement = "<span class='prettyNumber'>${1}</span>";
preg_replace($numberRegex, $replacement, $result);
```

This should change the value of `$result` to `some <span class='prettyNumber'>123</span> example string`. I haven't tested it though, but I think you get the idea anyway ;)

Comment: thanks. it will be useful when i inserted the number, but whats the solution for numbers which comes from database? for example a text which has some numbers in it.

Comment: you can handle the text right after you retrieve it from the DB and replace the number using regex for the same number wrapped in a span..

Comment: but that's not pure CSS obviously

Comment: In what language do you communicate with the DB?

Comment: i use ORM, no difference in db language.